# Can anyone help me translate these seals?

Tags: translation

Can anyone help me translate these seals? I have tried using google translate, google lens but they were no help. I also don’t know much about this so I don’t really know what I am looking for or even what direction to stamp them for clear reading, but I would like to learn more. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuzrq.jpg)[image][image] '[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. The characters in the first picture (left to right):

```
静安 peaceful or tranquil
```

2. The characters in the second picture (right to left):

```
大慈与一切众生乐 Great compassion have fun with all sentient beings

观世音菩萨 Avalokitesvara 

大悲拔一切众生苦 Great compassion relieves all sentient beings from suffering
```

Generally speaking, the responsibility of Avalokitesvara is have fun with all sentient beings and save them from suffering.

3. The characters in the third picture:
   [image: 吉祥如意]

```
吉祥 auspicious
如意 after your own heart
```

Sorry, I am not good at English

Answer (score 1):

1. The first stamp consists of two Chinese characters (left to right):

   > **安静 （ānjìng） quiet/silent, peaceful**

   The stamp on the left side is upside down. The right side is
   the correct way of writing the characters.
2. The engraved characters on the tablet are a Chinese antithetical couplet: two corresponding sides of antithetical lines and a middle part with a shorter phrase.

   This tablet goes (right to left, top-down)

   > **大慈予一切众生乐** （dà cí yǔ yí qiè zhòng shēng lè）**Great Mercy grants all sentient beings happiness.**

   > **观世音菩萨** （guān shì yīn pú sà）**Guanyin, the Bodhisattva of Compassion/Mercy** (Sanskrit Avalokitesvara)

   > **大悲拔一切众生苦** （dà bēi bá yí qiè zhòng shēng kǔ）**Great Compassion uproots all sentient beings sufferings.**

   The two lines of this couplet describe the key characteristics of Guanyin, the Bodhisattva, while the middle part reveals to whom this couplet pays tribute. As you can tell from the English translation, the two lines correspond one-to-one in their metrical length, the characters' properties, their meanings etc.
3. The last stamp reads from left topdown to right topdown. The one on the right side of your photo is the correct way.

   > **吉祥如意**（jí xiáng rú yì）**Good luck**

   This widely used four-word phrase consists of two two-word phrases that express good wishes.

   > **吉祥** (jí xiáng）—— **lucky/auspicious**.

   > **如意** （rú yì）—— (things will unfold) **as one wishes**.

   Hope it helps!